# can't reference file in app/assets without manifest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm a pretty seasoned rails dev but I'm kinda new to asset pipeline, and I had a question which is probably painfully simple. I wanted to play with the redactor js library, so I put the folder (which contains css and js files) into app/assets but I couldn't then just write

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "javascripts/redactor/redactor.min.js" %>
```

Rails kept saying it couldn't find the file. I eventually just moved it to the public folder, but my question is ... does everything that goes in lib/assets, vendor/assets or app/assets have to be precompiled (or referenced in a manifest) to be used?

PS: This is in the development btw. I have

```
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = true
```

set in development.rb

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to precompile it.  You can add it to the precompiled assets in `production.rb` which means you don't need a manifest file that only references one other file.

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( redactor.min.js )
```

You can use the unminified version in development which will help you find bugs.  It will minify automatically in production.

Fint out more about the asset pipeline [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).